# Can't update password using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

I'm using Hibernate + JSF + PrimeFaces. Now I wanna update password of admin but I always get error dialog. I can't figure out what wrong in my code. Hope anyone suggest me.

**loginBean (SessionScoped)**

```
public class loginBean {

    private Users username;
    private UsersDao userdao;

    /** Creates a new instance of loginBean */
    public loginBean() {
        userdao = new UsersDao();
        username = new Users();
    }

    public Users getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(Users username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void updateUser(){
        String msg;
        if(userdao.updateUser(username)){
            msg = "Updated Successfully!";
        }else{
            msg = "Error. Please check again!";
        }
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, msg, null);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(msg, message);
    }
}
```

**UserDAO.java**

```
public class UsersDao {
    public boolean updateUser(Users user){
        boolean flag;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        try{
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(user);
            session.beginTransaction().commit();
            flag = true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            flag = false;
            session.beginTransaction().rollback();
        }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

**xhtml**

```xml
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" life="3000" />
 <h:form id="tab">
        <h:outputLabel>Password</h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.username.password}" />
        <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" update=":growl" ajax="false" action="#{loginBean.updateUser}"/>
 </h:form>
```

Comment: And what does your log/console says?

Comment: "Error. Please check again!". I'm using if...else...

Comment: Your DAO's `updateUser` is of course throwing an exception (which is afterwards being caught and flagged). Which exception is it? Programmer level error traces are useful here, not the errors displayed to end-user.

Comment: @XtremeBiker "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Users__536C85E50425A276'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Users". I just wanna update password, why it reference PK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually performing a `save` operation into the [`Session`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html), instead of an `update` one, that's why you've got a *Violation of PRIMARY KEY* exception. You're telling Hibernate to add a new user with the same credentials, which is constrained by the Data Base.

In addition, and unrelated to the concrete problem, you should change your `Users` class name to `User`, as it refers to a concrete user.

Comment: Users class name is generated by Hibernate. I think if change, I maybe get error.

Comment: Hibernate doesn't auto-generate class names by itself. Probably another tool you're using does it (as Eclipse Hibernate Tools). You should change its name (after keeping a copy of what's now working), keep in mind your code could be read in the future, by yourself or other people, so having things properly named and commented is a **best practice**.